# Fill dataframe column with incremental sequence number

Tags: r

I'm trying to fill the remaining NA values of my dataframe column with incremental numbers, continuing from the last known number. Here's a sample of the problem:

```
df <- data.frame(var1 = c(1:5), var2 = c(1,2,3, NA, NA))
```

I want the two NA's in var2 to be 4 and 5 (i.e. a continuation from 1,2,3 ... to the end). I've got about 15 columns and 10,000 cases. Feels like it should be simple, the equivalent in excel is highlighting two previous cells and dragging the selection down (i.e. an extend)).

I looked at the complete() function in tidyr but I don't really understand it.

Comment: You are creating factor columns by quoting `NA`  It should be wthout quotes.  Also, I believe the case you showed is not a general case as it is at the end of the column.  May be you need to create an example that shows more patterns.

Comment: What I meant is suppose you have a column `v1 <- c(45, 26, 42, NA, NA, 1, 3, 7, NA, 24, NA, NA, 5, 7)`, what would be the expected output?  If your column is always in this pattern `v2 <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, NA, NA, 7, 8, 9, NA)` then just `seq_len(nrow(df))` would create the sequence

Comment: Good spot, I've fixed the NA's. In my code I'll sort my dataframe in ascending order by var2, so I think this example should be representative (NA's will therefore always be at the end)

Comment: As I said earlier, it is not very clear about the pattern.  If it is always a sequence ,then the previous code should work.  Otherwise  (assuming NAs at the end) `i1 <- is.na(df$var2);df$var2[i1] <- which(i1)[1] - 1 + cumsum(i1[i1])`

Comment: Maybe a sequence from the start would help?  `df %>% mutate(var3 = row_number())`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do:

```
df <- data.frame(var1 = c(1:5), var2 = c(1,2,3, NA, NA)) 

df$repl <- seq_len(nrow(df))

df$var2 <- ifelse(is.na(df$var2),
                  df$repl, df$var2)
```